# Nginx 502 Gateway Error: connect() to unix:/home/user/project/project.sock failed

Tags: nginx, http-error

I've gotten this error before, and can't seem to figure out why this occurred.

Ultimately its throwing a 502 Bad Gateway error.

if I do a `nginx -t`, I get:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

It appears my syntax in:
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`  looks good.

Here's the site in `sites-enabled`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my-server-name-ip-here>;

    error_log /home/user/project/nginx_error.error_log info;

    root /home/user/project/projenv;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
    }

}
```

Error Im getting:

```
connect() to unix:/home/user/project/project.sock failed
```

Here's my init script:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn          #respawn this on reboot
setuid user        #set as unix user 'jd' to run as
setgid www-data  #user used by nginx

env PATH=/home/user/project/projenv/bin
chdir /home/user/project
exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

any idea what I should fix??
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest checking the permissions on `/home/user/project/project.sock`

Comment: Permissions of that file: srwxrwx--- 1 myuser   www-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that this is probably a permissions error. Check that the socket is readable and writable by both client and server.

Comment: Im using nginx, not php5-fpm

Comment: What permissions and group should .sock be?

Comment: Try `chmod 664 sock_file_location`

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt fix the issue, even after restarting nginx

Comment: Please also see my init script, which doesnt fail